# Find out what high CPU usage apache process is actually doing?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, top, strace

Currently having a few issues with our server where, intermittently, we seem to get apache processes which just run and run, taking up 100% CPU.

When running top, we see the following:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
20788 www-data  20   0  318m  18m 3984 R  100  0.0  40:29.21 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
23523 www-data  20   0  319m  20m 4684 R  100  0.0   4:12.36 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I want to try and find out what script (or whatever it is) is causing this, so I tried:

```
 strace -p 20788
```

But that doesn't show any output at all (I've left it for about 10 minutes, and it shows nothing). From my understanding, this could mean it's stuck in an infinite loop, and there aren't any "system calls" to show.

Is there anything else I can do to show what's going on?

Thanks

**Edit -** Forgot to mention, this is a live server with a few hundred users at any one time! So I can't really just freely try changing config options and restart apache.

**Edit 2 -**  The backtrace (bt) from gdb doesn't seem to be all that useful when PHP isn't configured with --enable-debug - it only shows "execute()", but I need to know what PHP script is actually running.. is there any other way?

```
#0  0x00007f6c143fb0c5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#1  0x00007f6c143b040b in execute () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#2  0x00007f6c1438b970 in zend_execute_scripts () from     /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#3  0x00007f6c14337fe3 in php_execute_script () from     /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#4  0x00007f6c1441ae7d in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#5  0x00007f6c18912508 in ap_run_handler ()
#6  0x00007f6c1891297e in ap_invoke_handler ()
#7  0x00007f6c18922570 in ap_process_request ()
#8  0x00007f6c1891f398 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f6c18918fa8 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#10 0x00007f6c189271d0 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f6c1892793a in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f6c189284e7 in ap_mpm_run ()
#13 0x00007f6c188fd4a4 in main ()
```

Comment: Apache supports "graceful" restart, so why wouldn't you?

Comment: I *think* when we tried it previously, it couldn't restart gracefully because of the "stuck" apache processes... although that might be wrong, it was a while ago.

Comment: Another trick is to run another instance of apache on different port, redirecting _new_ connections to it.

Comment: @BT643 I know it's an old thread.....I have the same problem....and i don't know what php script cause that. Did you figure it out how to see what php script is actually running ???

Comment: @calin24 The "UPD" section in the accepted answer solved it for me in the end. I used mod_status with extended to find all the PHP files running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, in case you're feeling brave:

`gdb -p 20788`

then issue `bt` to see the stack-frame, for e. g.

And BTW, there's also [`ltrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) to mention — try it as well.

**UPD.**: well, ok, since now we have an idea that Apache is really running something, why wouldn't ya look at [`mod_status`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) output — [Extended](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#extendedstatus) one?

Comment: gdb isn't installed :( will have to wait until I go back to work tomorrow to see if I can install it without causing any issues..

`ltrace`didn't show any output either.

Comment: Just added the results from the gdb bt into the initial post.. doesn't really tell me much at all!

Comment: Oh, glad to see I've suggested the right direction. )

Comment: @BT643, see UPD.

Comment: Realised mod_status was already enabled by default, it was just limited to access from 127.0.0.1. I just logged in via SSH and piped the output to a file `curl domain.com/server-status > randomfile.html` - then viewed the file. 

Turned out it was an old developers code getting stuck in a loop (PHP file)! All sorted now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: wish i could vote for this answer but please explain more... why is it brave to run gdb? none of the other options are explained :( This is a great question

Comment: I'm no wizard to fulfil your wishes. ;)

Answer (score 7):

An very easy approach is to use `htop`. You can sort for the high CPU processes and then use

- s for `strace` a process
- l for `lsof` to see the open files of a processes
- L to `ltrace`.

I found that at least one of that options finds the script that generates the load and you can of course use this on a production web server to debug.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

- iotop (showing I/O on the system)
- netstat -t (showing connections)
- Take a look at the apache logfiles and find out what the server did last
- set some RLimits for the apache process. When these limits are reached the process will be killed, giving you some more information

Answer (score 0):

Your command should work provided you make an HTTP request that triggers that PID.

Maybe you want to temporarily re-configure Apache with only one child process?

Comment: Keep in mind that only one child process means that Apache can only serve a single request, and if that single child is stuck, Apache will not be able to serve any requests.

Comment: Can't do that as it's a live server with hundreds of concurrent users (have added that into the OP as it wasn't clear before)

Answer (score 0):

The PID of that apache instance is low, it might be the father of all the lot. That would certainly explain the high CPU usage (it stays around, others are spawned and recalled according to load). Much accumulated CPU time might just mean it has been running for a long time. No output from `strace(1)` just means it did no system calls. Yes, it might be in a tight loop, but apache is essentially I/O over the 'net, so I'd think it isn't doing anything useful. Strange 100% of one CPU, in any case.

Comment: Low PID doesn't necessarily mean it's an old process. PIDs have a max value, and wrap around so new processes can be created using low PIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Start a log with date/time, PHP script, and the PID using `getmypid()`

2) Then watch your server with `top`

3) When you see the apache process going high, search for the same date/time and PID in your logs. You should be able to find the problematic script.

Comment: This is an interesting solution but I can see it taking up more resources than it's worth, given that `mod_status` does its job quite well.